# Display User who deleted the Data

Tags: php, html

I have a form that allows the user to delete users from a database based on the extension number they enter. Before they can delete anyone they go through a login page. Once they delete a user from the data we receive an email stating what extension number was deleted. Is there a way that I could add which user deleted the data from the table ?

(Please note, I am aware of SQL injection issues and the use of mysql is depreciated. I will change them to PDO or mysqli once I have this issue sorted)

Currently the email looks like:

```
Extension Number 4324 was removed from the extension list.
```

Can I make it:

```
Extension Number 4324 was removed from the extension list by James.
```

- CODE

The login form:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Login</title> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head> 
<body id="body-color"> 
<div id="Sign-In"> 
<center><fieldset style="width:30%"><legend>Welcome Please Login Below</legend>
<form method="POST" action="connectivity.php"> 
Username: <br><input type="text" name="user" size="40"><br> 
Password: <br><input type="password" name="pass" size="40">
<br>
<br> 
<input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Log-In"> 
</form> 
</center>
</fieldset> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Connectivity.php

```
<?php
session_start();
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); 
define('DB_NAME', 'list'); 
define('DB_USER','root'); 
define('DB_PASSWORD','****'); 
$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 
/* 
$ID = $_POST['user']; $Password = $_POST['pass']; 
*/ 
function SignIn() 
{ 
session_start();  
if(!empty($_POST['user'])) 
{ 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM UserName where userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'") or die(mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query); 
if(!empty($row['userName']) AND !empty($row['pass'])) 
{ 
$_SESSION['userName'] = $row['pass'];
header("Location: index.php"); 
$_SESSION['CheckLogin'] = true;
} 
else 
{ 
header("Location: login.php");

} 
} 
} 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
SignIn(); 
} 
?>
```

The Delete.php form

```
<?php

require ("database.php");  

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['CheckLogin'])) { header("Location: login.php"); }




    if($_POST['action'])
{

$this_user_ext =$_GET['extension'];


    // sending query
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE extension = '$this_user_ext'")
    or die(mysql_error());          


include('maildelete.php');

$extension=$_POST['extension'];

header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
<center><form action="" method="post">
Enter 4 Digit Extension Number :<br><input type="text" name="extension">
<br><h2><input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete Extension">
<br></h2>
<h3>
<a href="index.php"> Main Menu </a> 
</h3>
</form>
</center>
```

and the maildelete.php

```
<?php

$extension = $_POST['extension'];
$department = $_POST['department'];

if ($_POST['department']=="IT DEPARTMENT") {
    $address2="alpineit@alpinemotors.co.za";
}

require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "****"; // SMTP server             // enables SMTP debug information 
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "****"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 587;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "****"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "****";        // SMTP account password
$mail->From = "no-reply@sdsads.co.za";
$mail->FromName = "Extension List";

$mail->AddAddress('jurgen@asdas.co.za', $address2, "");

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject  = 'Extension Deleted';
$mail->Body     = "Extension Number " . $extension . " from the " . $department . " was removed from the Extension List";

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}
echo 'Email Sent Successfully!';
?>
```

Comment: Yes when a user want to delete he is logged in .. so take that user email id  or name as you like and you can send to mail or store in a new table in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix.

I added $_SESSION['userName'];

so the line of code in my maildelete.php :

```
$mail->Body     = "Extension Number " . $extension . " from the " . $department . " was removed from the Extension List" . $_SESSION['userName'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Always put some extra column in your table, `created_by`, `created_at`, `updated_by`, `updated_at`, `deleted_by`, `deleted_at`. There value are the ID of logged-in user who perform the following operation.

By using this you can easily track the `add, update, delete` operation done by whom and on what date.

Comment: I have it working with the help of Dittos code below sir but it is posting the users password not the name. Any idea why sir?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have the username in the variable

```
$_SESSION['userName']
```

So it would be just to add that to the email message in **maildelete.php**

```
$mail->Body     = "Extension Number " . $extension . " from the " . $department . " was removed from the Extension List";
```

With this:

```
$mail->Body     = "Extension Number " . $extension . " from the " . $department . " was removed from the Extension List by ".$_SESSION['userName'];
```

Comment: this works but it is putting the users password not the users name

Comment: Was Removed from the Extension List by $9302D which is the user James password.

Comment: If the variable ``$_SESSION['userName']`` is displaying the password instead of the username, then you're capturing in such a variable the wrong value.

Comment: I Fixed it sir.